# Is there a way to customize the Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2 login page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, claims-based-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I'm using the Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2 app to perform SSO for a couple of internal apps but would like to customize the login page for each application to have a smoother user experience. I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Can the login page be customized depending on the source application from where the client is comming?

Comment: It's an MVC application so you can modify the stylesheet and html to your liking.

Comment: @Romoku: It's a SSO application so I'm thinking that it provides some hooks to attach custom CSS. I would like to keep the application's code intact as much as possible and not have to modify it each time I add a new application that's using it as SSO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I can't seem to find a way to do that." - How hard have you tried? ;)

The RP has the extra data fields - so you can hang like a CSS name off the RP in the registration database. Further you can get to that RP data from the signin page - quoting the comment in AccountController:

// you can call AuthenticationHelper.GetRelyingPartyDetailsFromReturnUrl to get more information about the requested relying party

btw - IdentityServer's github repo has an issue tracker - you should use that for questions.

Comment: I admit that I completely missed that comment in the controller but  later found the extra data fields on the RP and thought of using them. Thanks for the answer! Will use the github repo for other IdentityServer issues or questions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can always have the RP pass a custom query string param and customize off of that. But you're outside the bounds of WS-Federation at that point. Plus, you must think about the nature of SSO -- the user is really signing into the IdP, not the app. So changing the IdP to look like the app is somewhat disingenuous.

Comment: `the user is really signing into the IdP, not the app. So changing the IdP to look like the app is somewhat disingenuous`. I agree with that but these are existing internal apps whos users are accustomed to them and we are now changing the login for all. I want to make the change and hide to the users the fact that they are now doing SSO.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by customizing the **SignIn.cshtml** to adjust the style to what I need. Additionally, I have server side code in the top of **SignIn.cshtml** that does some string matching on the ReturnUrl (`Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]`). Then I show a different logo and header text based on some values I know to be unique for the different RP urls.

When upgrading to a new version of the ThinkTecture MVC, it will be a small job to update only this file to your specifics (just remember to have a copy of your modified **SignIn.cshtml** before you upgrade).