# Configure Login page for multiple application using Thinktecture IdentityServer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, thinktecture-ident-server, login-page

We are using Thinktecture IdentityServer for our applications to mange the Authentication Process. We need to configure the login page based on the requested application.

For Example if site one is calling the login page then logo1 should be displayed and if site 2 is calling the Login page then logo2 should be showed, meaning we need to configure two different login page for two different applications.

Is this possible using Thinktecture IdentityServer? If so let us know the process.

Please advice. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092458/is-there-a-way-to-customize-the-thinktecture-identityserver-v2-login-page) is the answer to the same question. I haven't tried customizing login page myself but it seems to me it involves light customization of IdentityServer. AccountController should be extended and new SignIn views added or existing SignIn view customized.